# Condinational razor brackets does not add up according to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a Razor view, where I use Bootstrap as my design/frontend baseline. Now I want to create a typical row/col-sm-6, and then make a new row for every second item.

However, when I do the following markup below, I get a:

```
Additional information: The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.
```

I just don't get why I get this error. If you see my markup below, there is the correct `{` and `}`, which should add up.

Any idea why I get the error?

```
@{ int index = 0; }
@if (Model != null && Model.Items != null)
{
    <div class="projects">

    @foreach (var project in Model.Items)
    {
        if (index % 2 == 0)
        {
            <div class="row">
        }

        <div class="col-sm-6 project">
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(project.Image))
            {
                <img src="@project.Image" />
            }

            <div class="project_title">@project.Title</div>

            @if (project.UserSnippet != null)
            {
                <img src="@project.UserSnippet.ProfilePic" class="post_image" />
                @Html.Partial("_UserSnippet", project.UserSnippet)
            }


            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(project.DescriptionSnippet))
            {
                <p class="project_description">@project.DescriptionSnippet</p>
            }

            <a href="/p/@project.Alias">Read more about project</a> @if (Model.ShowEditLink)
            {
                <a href="@Url.Action("EditProject", "Project", new { project_id = project.Id})">Edit project</a>
            }
        </div>

        @if (index%2 == 0)
        {
            </div>
        }

        }

    </div>
}
```

Comment: The error is correct, you have 1 extra }. It looks like the second to last one is the one you should remove.

Comment: No, the error is not correct at all. It's the broken Razor parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The broken Razor parser is at the origin of this problem. It is not capable of knowing that your opening `div` has a corresponding closing `div` because they are wrapped in `if` statements which are evaluated at runtime. And if for some reason the opening if statement evaluates to true and the closing evaluates to false you will end up with a broken markup. But in your case you know that this cannot happen because they have the same condition.

```
if (index % 2 == 0)
{
    @:<div class="row">
}
```

and here:

```
 @if (index % 2 == 0)
 {
     @:</div>
 }
```

Comment: @DarinDmitrov: Is it really "broken" or just "too conservative"?